# How can I align the columns of a space separated table in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with an arbitrary number of non-aligned columns separated with whitespace.

I would like to align the columns of the file.

I've looked at the `col` command, and it doesn't seem appropriate.

I could write an [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) script, but it seems like a more obvious command should exist.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功: It's more like that question is a duplicate of mine, since it was asked more than a year later. But it does have helped information - thanks for making the association!

Comment: Hey Richard, the current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newbie Google keywords on the title. It is sometimes random :-(

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You might want the `column` command, usually with `--table / -t` to produce basic tabular output:

From the man page:

> 

```
 -t, --table
```

Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the charac‐ters supplied using the --output-separator option.  Table output is useful for pretty-printing.

```
column -t [file]

# or from stdin
cat file | column -t

# For a quick demonstration, format the output of mount
mount | column -t
```

`column` has a lot of other complex options. `man column` for details.

If you don't have it, you can install it from the `bsdextrautils` package (formerly `bsdmainutils` and `bsdutils` prior to that).

Comment: Note: If you don't want to split on all whitespace, add the additional argument `-s`.  Eg to split on tabs `column -t -s$'\t'`  Note  the use of single quotes and the `$`, both are necessary to get `\t` to be recognized as a tab.

Comment: Been using terminals for a long time and I just learned about `column` today. Thank you!